# How to improve this trim-half-string algorithm?

Tags: c, string, trim

I have simple algorithm that clean the whitespace from half string until end. Here it is:

```
char a[] = "abc         "; /* The string to string to trim. */
printf("orginal [%s]\n", a);
char * org = strdup(a); /* duplicate the orginal string */
char * half_str = org + strlen(a) / 2; /* Get the half of string. */
strrev(half_str); /* reverse the string */
char * phs = half_str; /* Point to half_string */
char * news = malloc(strlen(half_str) + 1); /* The new string, without spaces. */
char * ptonews = news; /*Pointer to new string */

while(*phs) 
{
    /* if it's not whitespace like( ,\f,\r,\t,\v,\n) then concat to new string. */
    if(!isspace(*phs)) {
        *ptonews ++= *phs;      
    }
    phs ++;
}

/*Put the 0-terminator into new string. */
*phs ++ = '\0'; 

/* Replace the half_str with the newstring */
strcpy(half_str, news);

printf("new string [%s]\n", org);
```

it works fine. the output is:

```
orginal [abc        ]
new string [abc]
```

But the C code is a bit slow. How can I improve it?

Comment: Can you quantify "a bit slow"?

Comment: Are you are calling this code a *lot* ? If not then why are you concerned about performance ?

Comment: You're leaking a lot there. And could you clarify what "half-string" is?

Comment: Since your original string is 10 characters and you're supposedly cleaning whitespace from only half of it, why isn't your output at least 5 characters long?

Comment: I'm parsing text files. I was using a trim() method that remove all spaces, but doing some tests I see that I need remove only half string, then I written this this. It's 2seconds more slow that the trim() that remove all spaces.

Comment: This seems inefficient and error prone.  If your tests show you only need to operate on half the string, just terminate the middle of the original string and pass it to trim().

Comment: I think you don't need to copy and reverse the original string. Why don't you just iterate it in reverse order (I don't even understand why you want to do it reversed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a lot of unnecessary allocation.  Try something like this:

```
char a[] = "abc     ";
printf( "original [%s]\n", a);
int halfTrimmed = strlen(a)/2 + 1;
for( ; halfTrimmed>0; halfTrimmed-- )
    if( !isspace(a[halfTrimmed-1]) ) break;
char* news = malloc( halfTrimmed+1 );
strncpy( news, a, halfTrimmed );
printf( "new string [%s]\n", news );
```

In words, this algorithm finds the index of half the string (`halfTrimmed`), then starts looking at each character, starting at that index, until it finds the first non-space index.  It then copies from the beginning of the original string to the last non-space index into a new string, and you're done.